Disable specific account's credentials as Samba login on Windows 10
The way my computer is setup is as such: a main account with no password and an account with a password for using Samba securely. I want to disable the use of my main account as a login for accessing folders on my computer that I have shared with Samba. In this way, the Samba shares can only be accessed securely. How can I do this?
(Sure, I could just add a password to my main account, but I don't want to because passwords for logging into my personal compuyer are a pain.)

Is the computer a client to your Samba NAS, or is it the SMB server? If it's the former then I'm not sure why there's a need for two local accounts.

In the share permissions, you can set which users are allowed to access it. If your user with no password is an admin, you may want to disable the admin$ shares, since those permissions cannot be changed

@grawity_u1686 The computer is the server, I guess.

@Cpt.Whale That will not work for me. The account with no password is my main account, so I'm not going to remove administrator privileges from it, and these files are in its folders.

In that case it has nothing to do with Samba, I suppose, since it's a Windows system? Samba is primarily Linux/BSD-only, while Windows uses its own built-in SMB implementation.

That's already the default: accounts with empty passwords are only allowed to log in locally, i.e. at the physical console.
If you've somehow changed this so that Windows accepts network logons with an empty password, change it back through secpol.msc → "Security Options" → "Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only".
In the same secpol.msc you can also deny network logon for specific accounts using "User Rights" → "Deny access to this computer from the network". (SMB counts as a 'network' logon whereas RDP is 'interactive'; SSH could be either.)


I do not see "Security Options" or "User Rights".

I found them and those changes didn't work. In addition, I can't use the guest login with Samba now.
